# Example of chain map that induces the 0 homomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am looking for an example of degree wise free chain complexes $X,Y$ and a chain map $f$ between them such that $f$ is not chain homotopic to 0 and the induced homomorphism $f_* = H_*(X) \rightarrow H_*(Y)$ is zero. Can anyone give me a hint on how to find them ? I've been thinking of using Mayer Vietoris, but don't really know how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: I was sure that any free chain complex (at least one concentrated in nonnegative dimensions) with zero homology was contractible. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No complex is assumed to have zero homology. We only know that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is zero in homology. I am still looking for such an example or a proof that such a thing does not exist in the category of complexes of abelian groups, but I can give you an example in an other category (complexes of sheaves).